# String literal not working if passed as argument

Tags: c, x86-16, inline-assembly, bootloader, string-literals

I'm trying to write a bootloader in c and I noticed that string literals only worked if I passed them as a `char *`. 
If it Could help:

when I converted both versions to assembly I found one difference that was only in the working version which is

```
    mov     DWORD PTR -8[ebp], eax
    push    DWORD PTR -8[ebp]
```

just before calling puts

Here's my code :

```
asm("jmp main");

void putc(char c) {
    asm volatile("mov %%al, %0" :: "a"(c));
    asm volatile("mov %ah, 0x0e");
    asm volatile("int 0x10");
}

void puts(const char *s) {
   while(*s) putc(*s++);
}

void newl() {
    char s[] = { 0x0D, 0x0A, 0 };
    puts(s);
}

void clear() {
    asm volatile("mov ah, 0");
    asm volatile("mov al, 0x3");
    asm volatile("int 0x10");
}

void __attribute__((optimize("-O0"))) main() {
    clear();
    char * a = "Hello World";
    puts(a); // WORKS
    puts("Hello World"); // DOESN'T WORK (DOES NOT WRITE ANYTHING)
    newl();
}
```

LD.LD :

```
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS
{    
    . = 0x7C00;    
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text);
    } 
    .sig : AT(0x7C00 + 510)    
    {        
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }    
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame)
    }
}
```

How I compiled:

```
    gcc -m16 -c -ffreestanding -fno-pie -fno-exceptions -masm=intel -s -Os -static -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections main.cpp -o main.o
    ld -m elf_i386 -o main.elf -T ld.ld main.o
    objcopy -O binary main.elf main.bin
```

and I ran it with : `qemu-system-x86_64 -fda main.bin`

with `char * a = "Hello World"; puts(a);` :

objdump -h:

```
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000003  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000037  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000037  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .rodata       0000000c  00000000  00000000  00000037  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .text.main    00000051  00000000  00000000  00000043  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  5 .text.putc    00000014  00000000  00000000  00000094  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  6 .text.puts    0000002f  00000000  00000000  000000a8  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  7 .text.newl    00000029  00000000  00000000  000000d7  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  8 .text.clear   00000008  00000000  00000000  00000100  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  9 .comment      0000001f  00000000  00000000  00000108  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 10 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000127  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 11 .eh_frame     000000b8  00000000  00000000  00000128  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

[image: with pointer]

with  `puts("Hello World");`:

objdump -h:

```
    Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000003  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000037  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000037  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .rodata       0000000c  00000000  00000000  00000037  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .text.main    00000047  00000000  00000000  00000043  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  5 .text.putc    00000014  00000000  00000000  0000008a  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  6 .text.puts    0000002f  00000000  00000000  0000009e  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  7 .text.newl    00000029  00000000  00000000  000000cd  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  8 .text.clear   00000008  00000000  00000000  000000f6  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  9 .comment      0000001f  00000000  00000000  000000fe  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 10 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  0000011d  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 11 .eh_frame     000000b8  00000000  00000000  00000120  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

[image: without pointer]

Comment: "Not working" *how*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It just doesn't write anything

Comment: @TazeroutIslam Edit the question to include that information

Comment: @klutt It's in a comment

Comment: @klutt  I added pictures

Comment: You don't seem to be adding the constant data or BSS sections when linking. And have you looked at the object files what sections it contains? Or read the GCC documentation where it might place string literals? It's possible that the literal is in a section you don't add when linking.

Comment: I'm going to post the result

Comment: @TazeroutIslam Yes, but comments are meant to be temporary. A question should be self contained. It is a interesting question though.

Comment: Have you checked the asm to see how this super-broken inline asm compiled?  You seem to have already noticed that you needed to disable inlining into `main` because your functions have inline asm statements that modify registers without telling the compiler about it, and you depend on register modifications in one Basic Asm statement to not be stepped on before the next asm statement.  If you put `int 0x10` into a single Extended Asm `asm volatile` statement with proper constraints, you can compile with optimization.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Comment: @PeterCordes It worked in a way , why wouldn't it work in the other way ?

Comment: @Tazerout, your inline assembly is wrong in several ways, which can cause the compiler to generate unexpected code for it.

Comment: My best guess, though, is that the problem is related to not initializing static data properly, as @Someprogrammerdude mentioned.

Comment: I found a solution but i don't know what was wrong i posted the answer u can check it @prl

Comment: "happens to work" in some ways but not others is common for undefined behaviour.  Although the actual problem in this case might not be due to bad inline asm, it might be your linker script as earlier comments suggest.

Comment: @PeterCordes it was the linker (or the compiler i have no idea) but i couldn't figure out what was wrong