# Homemade kernel Inline assembly gives bad register name error. C

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I am coding a custom kernel (some of the work comes from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664165/Writing-a-boot-loader-in-Assembly-and-C-Part).
Here is the error

```
test.c: Assembler messages:
test.c:12: Error: bad register name `%dil'
ld: cannot find test.o: No such file or directory
objcopy: 'test.elf': No such file
```

And here are the files:

```
compile.sh

gcc -c -g -Os -march=x86-64 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o
ld -static -Ttest.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o test.elf test.o
objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin

test.ld

ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7c00;
    .text : AT(0x7c00)
    {
        *(.text)
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7dfe)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55)
    }
}
```

And here is the c (mixed with inline assembly) source

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

void printChar(char value);

void main() {
    printChar('c');
    printChar('i');
}

void printChar(char value) {
        __asm__("movb %0, %%al\n"
                "movb $0x0e, %%ah\n"
                "int $0x10\n"
                :
                : "r" ( value )
            );
}
```

I think that the error comes from the clobbered registers constrains (i played with them a bit, but because im in 16 bit, as this goes in the boot sectors, registers behave differently than when in 64 bit i think).
Any help is highly appreciated. Also, please note, even a tip to guide me on the right way is enough. I don't necessarily need the c code fix, what im primarily looking for is why this error happens. Thank you
edit:

I tried compiling with March i686 but it says The cpu you selected doesn't support the x86-64 instruction set and - fcf-protection=full –

I also added m16 to the gcc line and it compiles, but when I run ld it says i386 architecture of input file test.o is incompatible with i385:x86-64 output, so the gcc command is gcc -c -g -Os -march=i686 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o - m16

EDIT:
Thanks to @Peter Cordes i found the fix:

```
Build.sh

gcc -c -g  -march=i686 -Os -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test.c -o test.o -m32
ld -static -Ttest.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o test.elf test.o -melf_i386
objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin

And the c source code
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm("jmpl $0x0000, $main\n");

void printChar(char value);

void main() {
        printChar('c');
}

void printChar(char value) {
        __asm__(
                "int $0x10\n"
                :
                : "a"(value | (0x0e<<8))
                );
}
```

I Still havent understood what "a"(value | (0x0e<<8)) does. Can somebody give me some good resources to study for inlline assembly?

Comment: "bad register name `%dil`" In 16-bit code you cannot use the low byte of the 16-bit register `DI`. Only the registers `AX`, `BX`, `CX`, and `DX` have low and high bytes that you can address separately.

Comment: The 8-bit `SIL`, `DIL`, `BPL` and `SPL` registers are only available in 64-bit mode

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, you will not be able to produce anything useful from the C compiler if you switch to `.code16` while compiling 64 bit code.  It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Related: [String literal not working if passed as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63751892) is another question about this half-baked tutorial, or something similar anyway, with a linker script that doesn't include `.rodata` so string constants are unlikely to work, and unsafe inline asm.  (Except that question does use `-m16` and the right `ld` options.)

Answer (score 1):

Registers like `%dil` are only available in 64-bit mode. The tutorial uses the `-march=i686` option but this assumes your compiler is built to target a 32-bit environment, which the native Linux x86-64 compiler is not.

As @Peter Cordes indicated, you'll need to use `-m16`.

Alternatively, if you intend to pursue OS development beyond the tutorial, you should consider building a proper gcc cross-compiler for a generic target environment. Using the OS's native compiler usually causes problems with OS development. [This page](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) from OSDev is a good starting point.

Comment: Your first sentence is right, but `-march=i686` isn't the right option.  You want `-m16` to make 16-bit code (still using 32-bit operand-size and address size for most things; it's like `-m32` with a `.code16gcc` at the top).  The OP is misusing `-march=x86-64`, `-m64` is already the default, and `-march=x86-64` just sets the tuning and ISA-extensions to the default: baseline x86-64.  See [Can code built with g++ -march=x86-64 run on a 32-bit Operating System?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65791228) for another Q&A with the same misconception about `-march=x86-64`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: ```i686``` is what is used in the tutorial that was linked to, so I think it was a sufficient fix for the problem at hand. I should have added the general advice that trying to write a BIOS boot sector in C is usually a bad idea but that's the topic of that tutorial.

Comment: @sj95126 I tried compiling with March i686 but it says The cpu you selected doesn't support the x86-64 instruction set and - fcf-protection=full

Comment: The tutorial is assuming a GCC that defaults to `-m32`, e.g. in a 32-bit VM or an i686-elf-gcc cross-compiler on Windows.  It won't work on an x86-64 GNU/Linux desktop, like @TechTheGuy confirmed.  `-march=i686` might be useful with a 32-bit GCC that defaults to enabling `-msse2`, which would fault if you hadn't enabled it, because `i686` (ppro) doesn't imply SSE2.  (Or that random tutorial on the internet has the same misconception about what `-march=i686` does, and that's why they omitted `-m16` or `-m32`).  (Agreed that it's generally easier to write a boot sector in asm.)

Comment: You should fix your answer, not just leave the correct answer in comments.

Comment: @TechTheGuy: Just add `-m16` to the command line from the tutorial, like this answer says.  You might also need `-fcf-protection=none` to disable `endbr`

Comment: @Peter Cordes ok, in going to try. Thanks

Comment: @Peter Cordes it compiles, but when I run ld it says i386 architecture of input file test.o is incompatible with i385:x86-64 output

Comment: @TechTheGuy: Yes, obviously you need to *link* 32-bit object files into a 32-bit ELF executable, not the `ld` default of 64-bit.  Did you even try to google that error message?  e.g. use `gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -nostdlib` to link.

Comment: @Peter Cordes, I tried. An elf executable isn't a linux executable? In the os there is no kernel, because I'm coding it. So what is the right command for ld?

Comment: @TechTheGuy: You're making an ELF executable with `ld`, then copying the `.text` section out of it with `objcopy -O binary test.elf test.bin`.  If you use `file` on the `ld` output, it will tell you it's a Linux ELF 32-bit executable, because that's what the metadata says.  It would crash if you actually did run it on a Linux system, because it has 16-bit machine code that tries to use real-mode BIOS calls, of course.

Comment: @Peter Cordes so what are the right commands?

Comment: @TechTheGuy: you can link with `gcc -m32 -ffreestanding` like I said, or by adding `ld -melf_i386`, which you would already have found out if you'd looked at the google hits for that error message, plus the fact that I already told you that your build process does involve making a file whose metadata is Linux ELF executable, so everything about building a normal one applies to your case.

Comment: @Peter Cordes it compiles, and runs, but the code doesn't print characters on screen, and it did it before if I put a in place of r in the constrain.

Comment: @TechTheGuy: Use a debugger to single-step the code as it runs.  (e.g. the one built-in to BOCHS is good.)  If linking with gcc, you might need `-m32 -ffreestanding -no-pie -static -nostdlib`, so it probably is actually easier to just add `-melf_i386` to the `ld` command line, with GCC having so many defaults you need to change to use it to just link static executables.

Comment: @TechTheGuy: Now that you mention it, the inline asm is unsafe / broken: it overwrites AX without telling the compiler about it.  So yes, you should indeed use `"a"(c | (0x0e<<8))` as your input and remove both `mov` instructions, keeping just the `int`.  Really sounds like it's time to find a better tutorial, though, since that one doesn't even have working build commands or safe inline asm.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thank you so much. Can you give me some resources to study so I can understand that line that you just gave me? That magic line fixed the program

Comment: @TechTheGuy: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info has links to the official docs, and to various Q&As.  GNU C inline asm is hard to use; you need to understand asm, C, and how compilers "think", in order to be able to safely / correctly describe your asm to the compiler using constraints.  It's highly not recommended for beginners, learn asm and how C compiles to asm first.

Comment: @TechTheGuy: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm is part of why fuz was commenting that trying to build an MBR bootloader is not a good idea in the first place.  The other part is that it's only 512 bytes long.  Also, that specific tutorial's linker script omits include the `.rodata`, `.data`, and `.bss` sections, so any global vars would fail to work,  making the whole thing more like a "silly computer trick" than a template for further development.